# how to load set of records in one table and others set of records to different table in ssis

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, etl, ssis-2012

I have a scenario based question here.
Say I have a table which was million of records with few columns.I want to load the data to two different destination in ssis based on number of rows first 3 rows should go to one table and second set of three row should go to other table and this should repeat until all the records loaded  to the two destinations.

Table1:

```
ID
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
```

So first Target table should have records

```
1
2
3
7
8
9
```

and Second table should have

```
4
5
6
10
11
12
```

Please let me now the approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution (1): Using SQL (DENSE_RANK(), MODULO) + Conditional Split

You can use a similar SQL Command as OLEDB Source, it will generate a Column that split the data based on the row number.

```
SELECT ID, DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY ID % 3 ORDER BY ID) % 2 as DestinationTable 
FROM Table1 ORDER BY ID
```

After that you can use a conditional split component to split the flow into rwo destination.

*Note: When handling a huge amount of data, you have to make sure that you have created the corresponding indexes)*

---

## Solution (2): Using Script Component + Conditional Split

1. First you have the OLEDB connection manager you need *(Source and Destination Connections)*
2. Add a Data Flow Task
3. In the Data flow task, add an `OLEDB Source` which read from the Source Table
4. Add A Script Component where you need to implement the logic you described and you have to add an output column that contains the Destination Table ID.

*Script Code (VB.NET)*

```
Public Class ScriptMain
    Inherits UserComponent

    Private RowCounter As Integer = 0
    Private DestinationTableID As Integer = 1

    Public Overrides Sub Input0_ProcessInputRow(ByVal Row As Input0Buffer)

        RowCounter += 1

        Row.DestinationTable = DestinationTableID

        If RowCounter = 3 Then

            RowCounter = 0

            If DestinationTableID = 1 Then
                DestinationTableID = 2
            Else
                DestinationTableID = 1
            End If

        End If

    End Sub


End Class
```

5. Add A conditional Split that split the flow based on the Table ID *(If Table ID == 1 than insert data into Destination 1 else Destination 2)*
6. Connect each flow to the corresponding Destination

### Remark

If your goal is to distribute the data into two destination without any condition, you can only use only a conditional split transformation to split the data using (modulo) using the following expression *(where 2 is the number of destination you need)*

```
Row.ID % 2 == 0
```

Or you can use the [Balanced Data Distributor](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4123) to achieve that without any manual implementation.

Comment: Actually Questions is for distribute the data but based on the records count

Comment: @Ram i tried to solve the issue using SQL with no luck, so at least you have one solution until now, Hope that you get a better one. And i will notice you if i found one.

Comment: @Ram i found a solution using SQL, take a look into my answer update. Good Luck

Comment: Super up Thank you @Hadi

Answer (score 1):

you can use `Conditional Split Transformation`. For this,

- Click the Data Flow tab, and, from the Toolbox, drag the Conditional Split transformation to the design surface.
- Connect the Conditional Split transformation to the data flow by dragging the connector from the data source
- Double-click the Conditional Split transformation.
- In the Conditional Split Transformation Editor, build the expressions to use as conditions by dragging variables, columns, functions, and operators to the Condition column in the grid. Or, you can type the expression in the Condition column.
- The Click Ok.

In your case flow conditions can be `ID % != 0`   and `ID % 3 == 0`

Comment: I don't think that `MOD` work in this situation, it will not give the expected result. It will insert `1,2,4,5,7,8 ...` in one table and `3,6,9,12,15 ...` in the other one

Comment: yes I already think about that, but I am not sure if there is any other way of doing this without affecting performance. row_number can be used may be but I didnt try that on ssis

Comment: `MOD` is available but it will not give the expected result. the first and second rows will be inserted into the first table, the third row will be inserted in the other one, and so one...

Comment: I think he should use a Script Component to implement this scenario, take a look at my answer

Comment: `MOD(ID,3) = 0` is written `ID % 3 == 0` in SSIS Expression. I updated my answer about Distributed balancing please take a look

Comment: @Hadi Can we use some SQL logic because script component is asynchronous and may degrade the performance

Comment: @Ram I agree that Script Component affect performance, and i am trying to figure an SQL logic but also be aware that sometimes Script Component may be more performant than heavy SQL logic. So i am trying to figure an acceptable query